# AWS - Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I have a configured CloudFront distribution with an S3 bucket origin, which generally works. But, I am receiving the below error. I understand this is a common question, but I have reviewed all the guides and several StackOverflow posts, and believe I have configured everything properly, yet, am still having the problem.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://cdn.bodes.io/img/bodes.clear.light.small.png' from origin
> 'https://bodes.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Following the various AWS guides, I have set the following CORS policy on the S3 bucket:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

I have also set the following behaviors in CloudFront:

Allowed HTTP methods: `GET, HEAD, OPTIONS`

Cache HTTP methods: `+OPTIONS`

Cache policy and origin request policy - Cache policy: `CachingOptimized`

Origin request policy: `CORS-S3Origin`

Response headers policy - `SimpleCORS - Allows all origins for simple CORS requests`

I have also invalidated the entire Cloudfront distribution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Doh!  Turns out the Response headers policy needs to be:

```
CORS-With-Preflight
```

Apparently, `XMLHttpRequest` is part of the Preflight headers.